# How can I get grep to work with "->" as the pattern?

Tags: grep

I have this text in a file called `temp`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15776 Oct 15  2010 dnd-copy
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15776 Oct 15  2010 dnd-link
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15776 Oct 15  2010 dnd-move
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15776 Oct 15  2010 dnd-none
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15776 Oct 15  2010 dotbox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      5 Oct  8  2012 cross_reverse -> cross
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      5 Oct  8  2012 diamond_cross -> cross
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      6 Oct  8  2012 dot_box_mask -> dotbox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Oct  8  2012 double_arrow -> sb_v_double_arrow
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      9 Oct  8  2012 draft_large -> right_ptr
```

If I run `egrep -v 'lrwx' temp`, the last five lines are eliminated.

I expected that running `egrep -v '->' temp`, would eliminate the same five lines because `lrwx` and `->` occur on the same lines.

However, I get this error:

```
[09:43 PM] ~/Desktop $ egrep -v '->' temp
egrep: invalid option -- '>'
Usage: egrep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'egrep --help' for more information.
```

Trying `egrep -v '-\>' temp` doesn't help either:

```
[09:46 PM] ~/Desktop $ egrep -v '-\>' temp
egrep: invalid option -- '\'
Usage: egrep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'egrep --help' for more information.
```

(I get the same results with `egrep` or `grep -E`.)

Comment: `grep -v -- '->'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` is being interpreted as an option that `grep` should interpret for its own use due to the leading `-`. There are two methods you could use:

```
grep -- '->' # Explicitly declare end of arguments using --
grep '\->'   # Escape -, which still evaluates to -.
```

For the record, parsing ls is a bad way of finding symlinks that can quite easily lead to false positives or mangled data, especially if you're going to try and parse this further. Something like this would be better (in bash):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *; do
    [[ -h $file ]] || continue
    printf '%s -> %s\n' "$file" "$(readlink "$file")"
done
```